# PowerShell - Several processes updating the same log file

Tags: powershell, logfile

I have a PowerShell script running is parallel on several machines that write to the same log file, for that I'm using this simple line code: $line >> $LogFile

Obviously sometimes the file s locked when multiple process trying to update it
I want that in case the log file is locked the script will keep trying updating the file till he succeed

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Can you show us the error that you are getting when the file is locked?

Answer (score 0):

In general I would not recommend two different processes logging to the same file but here is an approach that should help:

```
function Log($line, $logFile) {
    $success=$false
    while (!$success) { 
        try {
            $line >> $logFile
            $success = $true
        } 
        catch [io.ioexception] {
            # Write-Host "Retrying log to file"
        }
    }
}

Log $line $LogFile
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prepare a Thread specialed in dealing with this problem. Firstly,Tou can declare a Queue，When the processes want to write the file,put it into the Queue，When the Queue is not empty let this process write the file